# Record in linux with QAudioInput and play it in windows

Tags: c++, qt, audio, alsa

For my purpose, I want to record sounds in raw format(only samples), 8kHz, 16bit(little endian) and 1 channel. Then, I would like to transfer those samples to the windows and play it with QAudioOutput. So I have two separated programs: one for recording voice with QAudioInput, and other one gives a file which is contained some samples, then I play it with QAudioOutput. Below is my source code for creating QAudioInput and QAudioOutput.

```
//Initialize audio
void AudioBuffer::initializeAudio()
{
  m_format.setFrequency(8000); //set frequency to 8000
  m_format.setChannels(1); //set channels to mono
  m_format.setSampleSize(16); //set sample sze to 16 bit
  m_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt ); //Sample type as usigned integer sample
  m_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian); //Byte order
  m_format.setCodec("audio/pcm"); //set codec as simple audio/pcm

  QAudioDeviceInfo infoIn(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice());
  if (!infoIn.isFormatSupported(m_format))
  {
      //Default format not supported - trying to use nearest
      m_format = infoIn.nearestFormat(m_format);
  }

  QAudioDeviceInfo infoOut(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());

  if (!infoOut.isFormatSupported(m_format))
  {
     //Default format not supported - trying to use nearest
     m_format = infoOut.nearestFormat(m_format);
  }
  createAudioInput();
  createAudioOutput();
}

void AudioBuffer::createAudioOutput()
{
  m_audioOutput = new QAudioOutput(m_Outputdevice, m_format, this);
}

void AudioBuffer::createAudioInput()
{
   if (m_input != 0) {
     disconnect(m_input, 0, this, 0);
     m_input = 0;
   } 

   m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_Inputdevice, m_format, this);

}
```

These programs work well in windows and Linux separately. However, it has a lot of noise when I record a voice in Linux and play it in windows.

I figure out captured samples in windows and Linux are different. First picture is related to captured sound in Linux and second one for windows.

Captured sound in Linux:
[image: captured sound in Linux]

Captured sound in Windows:
[image: captured sound in Windows]

A bit more on details is that silence in Windows and Linux is different. I tried many things including swapping bytes, even though I set little endian in both platforms.

Now, I am in doubt about alsa configuration. Are there any missed settings?

Do you think it will be better if I record voice directly without using QAudioInput?

Comment: can you check that `isFormatSupported` true in both cases?

Comment: Both input and out are true!

Comment: Remove both lines that calculate the `nearestFormat` code and put an `abort()` there instead, then record a new file on linux, move file over to windows, and retry there. Make sure you use fresh builds on both, with the change applied, and that you're playing the newly captured file transferred from the linux machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voice is UnSignedInt, but sample value has both negative and positive value! It seems you had trouble in capturing. Change `QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt` to `QAudioFormat::SignedInt`.